# Roslyn Run Code in AppDomain

Tags: c#, roslyn

I added Roslyn my project.
Roslyn can run script from string like

```
using Roslyn.Scripting.CSharp;

namespace RoslynScriptingDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var engine = new ScriptEngine();
            engine.Execute(@"System.Console.WriteLine(""Hello Roslyn"");");
        }
    }
}
```

but I wanna access the controls,properties,variables in the form.
For Example There is a textbox in form.

```
var engine = new ScriptEngine();
engine.Execute(@" textbox1.Text="SK"; ");
```

Can I access controls in Roslyn?

Comment: Have you seen the examples here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2011/12/02/introduction-to-the-roslyn-scripting-api.aspx . It seems like if you want to access `textbox1` from the script it would need to be public.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a host object for your script session that has a public property for the controls you want to access.